# K-Fold Cross validation with different (merged) datasets

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn, data-mining

I have 15 different datasets (a list of 15 `pandas.DataFrame`) of the same problem which i would like to study from the perspective of a single classifier doing K-Fold CV. Currently, i am running some experiments with the following structure:

```py
# Manual 15-Fold CV
for i in range(len(datasets)):
   train_sets = [datasets[j] for j in range(len(datasets)) if j != i]
   test_set = datasets[i]

   train = pd.concat(train_sets)
   clf = ...
   clf.fit(...)
   ...
```

As you can see, i need to treat each dataset as a fold for K-Fold, instead of simply merging all datasets into a single one and running default `cross_val_score()` or something similar.

This works great when running singular experiments, but i'd like to use `GridSearchCV` to better explore my models. So, the question is: is there any way of creating a custom `KFold` predefining what will be each fold and pass it to `GridSearchCV`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from the [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html)

> cv: int, cross-validation generator or an iterable, default=None

> An iterable yielding (train, test) splits as arrays of indices.

so you can create a list of tuples, and merge all the data into a single dataset while maintaining indicies to them that you can use in those tuples,

<s>so if you have the indicies in a list of numpy arrays called indicies.</s>

**edit:** this is untested but it should work.

```py
indicies = []
train_test_set = []
last_element = 0
for j in range(len(datasets)):
    train_test_set.append(datasets[j])
    indicies.append(np.arange(last_element,last_element+len(datasets[j])))
    last_element += len(datasets[j])

cv_list = []
for i in range(15):
    cv_train = np.hstack([indicies[x] for x in range(15) if x != i])
    cv_list.append((cv_train,indicies[i]))
```

and just pass cv_list to the function.

**Edit2:** fixed typo in code.

Comment: So, i can just pass the predefined train/val datasets for each run with this `cv_list`, right?

Comment: yes, each entry of indicies, should be a numpy array containing the indicies of the 'fold' in the entire dataset, and this way it'll create the proper train/test split based on the entries of indicies.

Comment: and just pass the entire dataset as one huge matrix to the function.

Comment: I'll try and come back here to tell you if it worked! Thanks for the help!

Comment: I'm sorry, i realized i didn't understand how to get the `indicies` array. Could you please extend your answer?

Comment: done, it "should" work.

Comment: Yes, it worked but in the first `for` loop, you are using a `j` index that doesn't exist. Did you mean `for j in range(...)` in the first loop?

Comment: Yes, small typo

Comment: Worked as expected! Thank you for your help! :)